# How to get the underlying connection inside a transaction using jOOQ?

Tags: java, jdbc, transactions, java-8, jooq

I'm using jOOQ inside an existing project which also uses some custom JDBC code. Inside a [jOOQ transaction](http://www.jooq.org/doc/3.6/manual/sql-execution/transaction-management/) I need to call some other JDBC code and I need to pass through the active connection so everything gets inside the same transaction.

I don't know how to retrieve the underlying connection inside a jOOQ transaction.

```
create.transaction(configuration -> {
    DSLContext ctx = DSL.using(configuration);

    // standard jOOQ code
    ctx.insertInto(...);

    // now I need a Connection
    Connection c = ctx.activeConnection(); // not real, this is what I need
    someOtherCode(c, ...);
});
```

Reading the docs and peeking a bit on the source code my best bet is this:

```
configuration.connectionProvider().acquire()
```

But the name is a bit misleading in this particular use case. I don't want a new connection, just the current one. I think this is the way to go because the configuration is derived and I will always get the same connection, but I'm not sure and I can't find the answer in the documentation.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

jOOQ's API makes no assumptions about the existence of a "current" connection. Depending on your concrete implementations of `ConnectionProvider`, `TransactionProvider`, etc., this may or may not be possible.

Your workaround is generally fine, though. Just make sure you follow the `ConnectionProvider`'s SPI contract:

```
Connection c = null;
try {
    c = configuration.connectionProvider().acquire();
    someOtherCode(c, ...);
}
finally {
    configuration.connectionProvider().release(c);
}
```

The above is fine when you're using jOOQ's `DefaultTransactionProvider`, for instance.

Note there is a pending feature request [#4552](https://github.com/jOOQ/jOOQ/issues/4552) that will allow you to run code in the context of a `ConnectionProvider` and its calls to `acquire()` and `release()`. This is what it will look like:

```
DSL.using(configuration)
   .connection(c -> someOtherCode(c, ...));
```

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder for your fast answer. I'm using `DefaultTransactionProvider`. The `ConnectionProvider` is `DataSourceConnectionProvider` and no `DefaultConnectionProvider`. I've seen that the `ConnectionProvider.release()` method does nothing in the latter and closes the connection in the former. The `DefaultTransactionProvider` says in the docs that _intended to work with `DefaultConnectionProvider`_. Am I in trouble? ;-) Seems that I might be killing the transaction too soon.

Comment: @sargue: No, you're not in trouble. The local `Configuration` is derived from your own `Configuration`. The `DefaultTransactionProvider` locally uses a `DefaultConnectionProvider` and keeps the `Connection` for the scope of a transaction. I suspect this deserves more documentation

Comment: Thanks @LukasEder. Done some edit of the answer and accepted as the best current solution. Maybe a method on the transaction provider would be useful? `configuration.transactionProvider().currentConnection()` which will return null on the `NoTransactionProvider` or throw some exception on other, more exotic, providers which can't support this. I can create an issue in GitHub if you think it might be useful.

Comment: Well, my edit has been rejected so I'm putting it here because I really thinks it improves the answer. >>> Even if the `release()` invocation might seem to close or rollback the connection it does not. Whenever you start a transaction with `create.transaction()` the derived configuration uses internally a new `ConnectionProvider` which reuses the same connection over and over again until the transaction is over. This `ConnectionProvider` is the `DefaultConnectionProvider` initialized with one connection acquired from the original configuration's `ConnectionProvider`.

Comment: @sargue: Edit: You've just met the stack overflow police. Congrats :). `currentConnection()` method: We can't add methods to the `TransactionProvider` anymore. We'll need another way, if we need a way at all...